# How do I recursively reverse a linked list?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list, reverse, singly-linked-list

**Input: 5 -> 9 -> 8 -> 3 -> 1 -> 7**

**Expected Output: 7 -> 1 -> 3 -> 8 -> 9 -> 5**

**Issue:**

When I display the reversed linked list the result is 5. This is an issue because this should be the tail and not the head. The rest of the nodes are missing in the display well.

**Question:**

Is there an issue with the code base that is preventing the traversal from the head to the tail and changing the pointers to reverse the list?

**Code:**

*LinkedList:*

```
class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
    this.size = 0;
  }

  insertFirst(item) {
    if (this.head !== null) {
      const newHead = new _Node(item);
      let oldHead = this.head;

      oldHead.prev = newHead;
      newHead.next = oldHead;
      this.head = newHead;
    } else {
      this.head = new _Node(item, this.head);
    }

    this.size++;
  }

  insertLast(item) {
    if (!this.head) {
      this.insertFirst(item);
    } else {
      let tempNode = this.head;
      while (tempNode.next !== null) {
        tempNode = tempNode.next;
      }
      tempNode.next = new _Node(item, null, tempNode);
    }
    this.size++
  }
}

module.exports = LinkedList;
```

*Main:*

```
const LinkedList = require("./LinkedLists");
const { reverse } = require("./Reverse");
const { display } = require("./Supplemental");

function main() {
  let SLL = new LinkedList();

  SLL.insertFirst(5);
  SLL.insertLast(9);
  SLL.insertLast(8);
  SLL.insertLast(3);
  SLL.insertLast(1);
  SLL.insertLast(7);

  reverse(SLL);
  display(SLL);

  return SLL;
}

console.log(main());
```

*Reverse:*

```
reverse = (SLL) => {
  let curr = SLL.head

  if (!curr) {
    return;
  }

  if (!curr.next) {
    SLL.head = curr;
    return;
  }

  let tmp = reverse(curr.next);
  curr.next.next = curr;
  curr.next = null;
  return tmp;
}


module.exports = { reverse };
```

*Display:*

```
display = (SLL) => {
  let currentNode = SLL.head;

  if (!SLL.head) {
    return null;
  }

  while (currentNode !== null) {
    console.log(currentNode.value);
    currentNode = currentNode.next;
  }

  return;
};
```

Comment: I don't think reverse needs to be recursive. You could just pop the elements from the original list and push them onto the reversed list until the original list is empty.

Comment: You've got some type errors. Does reverse take a node or does it take a list? You have it trying to do both.

Comment: @Khobalt It takes a list, SLL. And I'm using a node within the function.

Comment: At the global scope you call reverse on SLL. Then in the function you do the recursive call on a node. There's no such thing as node.head so curr is going to be null the second time you call it.

Comment: Have you learned how to use a debugger and step through code yet?

Comment: @Khobalt - "At the global scope you call reverse on SLL..." I see. This makes sense why only 5, the first node, is displayed. I've learned how to step through with the debugger. VS Code's debugger has been a little wonky. I've been console logging a lot.

Comment: @Khobalt - I was able to debug the code to see how the lines are working. I added a new code base below that works. I am curious to know what `return tmp` is doing?

Answer (score 0):

Can someone tell me what `return tmp` is doing in the Reverse.js file?

**(1) Removed display from Main.js**

**(2) Edited Main.js:**

```
const LinkedList = require("./LinkedLists");
const { reverse } = require("./Reverse");
const { display } = require("./Supplemental");

function main() {
  let SLL = new LinkedList();

  SLL.insertFirst(5);
  SLL.insertLast(9);
  SLL.insertLast(8);
  SLL.insertLast(3);
  SLL.insertLast(1);
  SLL.insertLast(7);

  const result = reverse(SLL.head);
  console.log(result);

  return SLL;
}

return main();
```

**(3) Edited Reverse.js:**

```
reverse = (curr, prev = null) => {
  if (!curr) { 
    return prev;
  }

  let tmp = reverse(curr.next, curr);

  const temp = curr.next;
  curr.next = prev;
  curr.prev = temp;

  return tmp;
}

module.exports = { reverse };
```